Inject initial command into an interactive command after 10 seconds in a terminal?
I'd like to inject an initial cmd into an interactive process 10 seconds later, the purpose is to execute initial cmd inside the interactive session, 10 seconds after the interactive cmd is launched.
The following demonstrate the diagram of cmd result:
  (echo "initial cmd" && cat) | interactive cmd
  <<other cmds (first 10 seconds)
  <<initial cmd (10 seconds later put initial cmd here) 
  <<[result of initial cmd] 
  <<(keep interact, not exit)

I look at the other related topic:
How can I pipe initial input into process which will then be interactive?
which is close to my solution, but it injects the initial cmd at the begining of interactive cmd.
I want to inject the initial cmd 10 seconds later(not at the begining), and keep the interactive terminal.
Is there simple solution?
